# Removing duplicate nodes from xml using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate nodes from xml based on combination of node attribute value and actual node value using PowerShell.

As in below example, based on combination of attribute 'name' and the actual value: 2nd and 4th node are same. So one of these should be removed.

Input XML:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the xml as text/code, not pictures

Comment: Input XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<globalvariables>
  <variable name="aaaa">11111</variable>
  <variable name="bbbb">11111</variable>
  <variable name="bbbb">22222</variable>
  <variable name="bbbb">11111</variable>
</globalvariables>

Comment: Expected Output:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<globalvariables>
  <variable name="aaaa">11111</variable>
  <variable name="bbbb">11111</variable>
  <variable name="bbbb">22222</variable>
</globalvariables>